# Recover battery management system for screwdriver without external power

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated

I used one of many (Battery Management System) BMS on the marker to convert my Ca-Ng battery to Li-ion one. 
An example: [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-12-6V-8A-W-Balance-Li-ion-Lithium-18650-Battery-BMS-PCB-Protection-Board/32595691934.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.nj6jcs&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10065_10151_10068_5400011_5430020_5410020_10304_10307_10137_10060_10302_10155_10154_5370011_10056_10055_10054_10059_100031_10099_10103_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_5380020_10171_10326_5390020_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10315_10078_10079_10073_5420011,searchweb201603_16,ppcSwitch_4&btsid=de216ad5-0c31-4d1a-afa9-dd8012f26b5b&algo_expid=5c415cd0-56f6-437c-91b1-ed18296ba9c2-1&algo_pvid=5c415cd0-56f6-437c-91b1-ed18296ba9c2)

When bit is stuck or when you want to fixate a drill on drilling position you can trigger safety mechanism and BMS will disconnect your screwdriver from the battery. I suspect that this is over-current protection. And I am very happy it exists rather than burning motor. 
But drawback of this is that to recover to normal operation mode i need to connect BMS back to an external power source, even for a second to unblock protection circuit.

On another screwdriver I have (branded, Li-on) when drill is stuck or other over-current activity happens power will be disconnected but in less then 1 minute screwdriver is operational again without any extra actions.

What can be done to implement such functionality? I suspect that there should  be some sort or multiple-use (thermo-)fuse that would recover on its own?

Comment: To my taste, both behaviors are not acceptable, nor waiting whole minute, nor connecting-disconnecting the circuit. You need to get a better BMS, or design your own to accommodate the stall current of your drill, and to have instant recovery.

Comment: Ali, what you say makes sense, so I am open to any ideas. if something else could be used--let me know